# How to create a button that underlines text?

Tags: ios, uitextview

I created a button that needs to underline text that is in the selectedElement.

I have this code so far, but it only works if you HIGHLIGHT the text and then press underline. I need it to make it underlined without having to highlight the text.  Any help on how to go about making this undo the underline if you press the underline button again is also welcomed. Thank you so much for your time! I'm a novice ):

```
-(void)underlineTextButton{
    UITextView selectedText = (UITextView ) selectedElement;
    NSRange range = selectedText.selectedRange;
    NSTextStorage *textStorage = selectedText.textStorage;
    [textStorage addAttribute: NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName
    value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle]
    range:range];
}
```

Comment: Please check [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
   //If it gonna be the static text
   _textView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedText alloc] initWithString:@"Your <u>underlined</u> text goes here.."];

  // If need to by text using regex
  NSRange r;
  NSString *s = _textView.text;
  while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"patternText" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
    s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<u>%@</u>", patternText]];
  _textView.attributtedText = [[NSAttributedText alloc] initWithString:s];

}
```